# Is an uncensored version of Dark of the Sun available?

Tags: alternate-version, censorship

I notice that some modern editions of Dark of the Sun (1968) are labeled as "remastered" which means they have been censored to remove some of the scenes.

However, other editions, such as the Blu-Ray, do not have such a label. Are they all the same censored cut, or are modern uncut editions available?

Comment: That's not what remastered means

Comment: If a movie or musical recording is remastered, a new recording is made of the old version, using modern technology to improve the quality

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, I know. When I say that it "means" they have censored, I mean that is one way you can tell that it is the censored version of the movie, not that it means that in general.

Comment: Runtime is 101 mins. If it's been cut it will be shorter.

Comment: No. Remastered is not the same as censoring, in fact it the opposite. A remastered version has the same footage just improved quality.

Comment: Again, remastered does NOT mean edited or censored so your whole premise is incorrect.

Comment: @Tetsujin That is a helpful idea, but the "remastered" edition which is known to be censored is listed as having a runtime of 100 minutes, so either your running time is incorrect or the video publishers are lying about their runtime.

Comment: … or it's only censored in certain markets… Usually in the UK they're more likely to put back scenes that were originally cut for 'content' than they are to take them out.

Comment: Maybe no closer in the search but I found these - https://moviesanddrinks.com/2019/10/16/dark-of-the-sun-1968-movie-review/ and https://moviechat.org/tt0062863/The-Mercenaries/58c7293c5ec57f0478f0e651/Uncut-Version Neither gives the length of an uncut for comparison, but between them they do tell what the cuts were. I just … ermm.. borrowed… an online copy & it's 1:40:33 which will be why some say 100 mins & others 101 - depends on whether you round up or down. It's hard to tell whether either of these links reveals *substantial* cuts were made.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the modern versions are the same as the US theatrical release per the following comments from a movie buff forum:

> As I understand it, the DVD is identical to the U.S. theatrical
> release from '68, so I'd bet that your 35mm print is, categorically
> speaking, uncut.
>
> However, there have been reports that a longer cut was submitted by
> director Cardiff to the studio, and that longer/bloodier version
> underwent heavy censorship from studio execs and later the MPAA. Rumor
> has it that Cardiff's cut was shown at some international festivals
> and was exhibited overseas (in Spain, I believe).
>
> Also, Tarantino (I know, I'm tired of seeing his name all over these
> boards too) reportedly found an uncut foreign print (not sure if it's
> 35mm or 16mm) and spliced the extra bits into a nicer English language
> print, which he then screened in Texas. People have blogged about it
> online.
>
> The real tell, though, is the film itself. Two scenes in particular
> are visibly censored: 1. Jim Brown's death scene. 2. The final
> showdown between Rod Taylor and the German guy. Watch them again and
> you'll see what I mean.
>
> Regardless, DARK OF THE SUN is one of my favorite films of the '60s.
>
> reply  share [–] geode 6 years ago The interesting thing is that Jack
> Cardiff's comments on the film that are in print indicate nothing
> about censoring a first cut or there being differences in foreign
> releases. The only thing I could find about a possible Tarantino find
> of an uncut print seems to be here. it would appear that he searched
> for an uncut print and finally found one, but previous finds were
> apparently TV prints. Yes, those were always censored. I would guess
> that the print he found was a 16mm print as it was said that it was
> LPP. Those were only stuck from the early 1980's onward, and there
> were no theatrical re-issues in that time frame to my knowledge.

Comment: Ideally, you would link back to this forum since you quote significantly from it.